# VB.NET not deleting records from SQL DB

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm having some rather annoying issues with an app I'm trying to write.

I have a DB with a small table ("main") that i entered data into manually when i created the table. I can delete one of the 3 rows that I manually inputted, no problem, but if I add a row from the app it doesn't save to the database and I can't delete it.
Additionally, none of the values that I've edited save to the DB. I suspect that these two issues are related and was hoping you could help me figure out what's wrong.

here's the code for the "delete" button:

```vb
Private Sub btnSearchDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearchDelete.Click

    Try

        Me.MainTableAdapter.Delete(searchIP.Text, searchSubnet.Text, searchVLAN.Text, searchAlive.Checked, searchReserved.Checked, searchUser.Text, searchDate.Text, searchFail.Text)


        ' updates system message bar for 1 second
        Dim tmCurTime As DateTime = Date.Now
        Dim wait As Int16 = 1  ' Time in seconds
        Do
            sysmsg.Text = "Deleted record."
            sysmsg.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop Until DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, tmCurTime, Date.Now) = wait
        sysmsg.Text = ""

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox("Delete failed!" - ex.Message)

    End Try
    Ds.AcceptChanges()
    Me.MainTableAdapter.Update(Me.Ds.main)

    'clears search filter
    Me.MainBindingSource.Filter = Nothing
    Me.MainTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Ds.main)

    grid.Refresh()

End Sub
```

(grid is referring to the datagridview on the main app page)

i realize my code is probably, um, extremely messy -- I'm super new the development side of things and this is only the 3rd app I've worked on so far.

Any help you could give would be appreciated.

::EDIT::
ok, so this is what `MainTableAdapter.Delete()` is calling in SQL-speak:
`DELETE FROM [dbo].[main] WHERE (([IP] = @Original_IP) AND ((@IsNull_SUBNET = 1 AND [SUBNET] IS NULL) OR ([SUBNET] = @Original_SUBNET)) AND ((@IsNull_VLAN = 1 AND [VLAN] IS NULL) OR ([VLAN] = @Original_VLAN)) AND ((@IsNull_ALIVE = 1 AND [ALIVE] IS NULL) OR ([ALIVE] = @Original_ALIVE)) AND ((@IsNull_RESERVED = 1 AND [RESERVED] IS NULL) OR ([RESERVED] = @Original_RESERVED)) AND ((@IsNull_USR = 1 AND [USR] IS NULL) OR ([USR] = @Original_USR)) AND ((@IsNull_DATE = 1 AND [DATE] IS NULL) OR ([DATE] = @Original_DATE)) AND ((@IsNull_FAIL = 1 AND [FAIL] IS NULL) OR ([FAIL] = @Original_FAIL)))`

Comment: Remove `Ds.AcceptChanges()`

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I've tried it both with and without `ds.acceptchanges()` and it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Please set the compile option [Strict ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c553zwz0(v=vs.100).aspx). I'm having a hard time subtracting `"Delete failed!" - ex.Message`.

Comment: better?
`MsgBox("Delete failed!" + ex.Message)`

Comment: Run this code and report back the result: `Dim rowsDeleted As Integer = If((Me.Ds.main.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted) Is Nothing), 0, Me.Ds.main.GetChanges(DataRowState.Deleted).Rows.Count)`

Comment: its showing 0 for rows deleted.

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure the problem is this part `Me.MainTableAdapter.Delete(...)`. Please confirm that it actually find and removes rows `MsgBox(Me.Ds.main.Rows.Count) : Me.MainTableAdapter.Delete(searchIP.Text, searchSubnet.Text, searchVLAN.Text, searchAlive.Checked, searchReserved.Checked, searchUser.Text, searchDate.Text, searchFail.Text) : MsgBox(Me.Ds.main.Rows.Count)`

Comment: Ok, so it shows as deleting rows correctly, but only when its a row that was added by hand through editing the table in VS2012. If i add the row with the app, it doesn't actually delete, however it does reflect the new row on the `Me.DS.main.rows.count`.

Comment: Are you sure the `Me.MainTableAdapter.DeleteCommand` is properly set? Run this code: `MsgBox(If((Me.MainTableAdapter.DeleteCommand Is Nothing), "DeleteCommand is null.", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.MainTableAdapter.DeleteCommand.CommandText), "DeleteCommand.CommandText not set.", ("DeleteCommand.CommandText: " & vbNewLine & Me.MainTableAdapter.DeleteCommand.CommandText))))`

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå see my edit above, i think the syntax of the `maintableadapter.delete()` is the issuse, but I have no real idea.

Comment: i THINK i might have just fixed it -- I changed the `maintableadapter.delete()` command to `DELETE FROM main WHERE ip = @IP` -- i'll do some testing

Comment: Thanks for all your help! it looks like changing the SQL command to `DELETE FROM main WHERE ip = @IP` did the trick.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution:)